# Do AirPlay devices still work with iTunes on Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows, airplay

I use iTunes (ver 12.13.1.3) running on Windows 10 to manage my music library. I use AirPlay to stream music from that Windows machine to my Apple TV, which is connected to my home entertainment system. It works fine. I'd like to set up a separate AirPlay receiver so I can play songs into the sound system of a different room. Currently-available devices like the [WiiM Mini AirPlay2 Wireless Audio Streamer](https://a.co/d/6uAgksV) claim to be AirPlay2 compliant (though I find no information about "AirPlay2" at [Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/airplay/). Nevertheless, all the vague sales-oriented blurbs (from Apple as well as other vendors) say you can stream "from Apple devices" or "stream your favorite tunes from iOS and Mac devices". But does that still include iTunes running on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying the WiiM device. The Windows version of iTunes connected to it without issue.